# $compile not working ever since upgraded to Angular 1.3

Tags: angularjs, migration

I've upgraded to Angular 1.3.15 and the following code stopped working correctly:

```
var newScope = $scope.$new();
angular.extend(newScope, data);
var html = '<ng-include src=\'"' + templateUrl + '"\'></ng-include>';
var newHtml = $compile(html)(newScope);
```

After the `$compile` the data of the `newHtml` is `data: " ngInclude: undefined "`.
I tried looking at breaking changes that might have been in 1.2 or in 1.3 but didn't find anything relevant.

Ideas?

[edit]

After reading some more examples online, for example here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4505

I saw that when I run this code with the old AngularJS version, I get a return element of `ng-include.ng-scope` while with the new version I get `comment`.
It would make sense if it added 2 elements - comment and ng-include, but it doesn't, just the comment.
No idea how to continue from here on

Comment: I don't know if that's related, but why do you need both single quotes and double quotes around your `templateUrl`?

Comment: To indicate thats a path in my directory rather than a full path or web url.
Btw this code worked great with Angular 1.1

Comment: I suppose you miss wrapping the templateUrl with quote, like `src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"`

Comment: indulge me. try `var html = '<ng-include src="' + templateUrl + '"></ng-include>';`

Comment: It resolves down to:

`<ng-include src='"partials/geo/popups/click/marker-InstagramPost.html"'></ng-include>`

@yarons will gladly idulge. tried and still same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so sure why, but I solved it by dynamically creating a div element, injecting its html and passing that to the $compile.

Like this:

```
var html = "<ng-include src=\"'" + templateUrl + "'\"></ng-include>";
var div = $('<div>');
div.html(html);
var newHtml = $compile(div)(newScope);
```